# What should I add so that when the system detects some specific object it will play an alert sound?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have done the object detection api using webcam, the system was run successful detected object, now i want to add, when the system detected some specific object it will play diff alert sound

```
while True:
    # Acquire frame and expand frame dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    ret, frame = video.read()
    frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

    # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        frame,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8,
        min_score_thresh=0.60)
    #if xxxxx:
    #    alert.play()
    #else:
    #    pass
    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
```

my system is auto detect dangerous weapon, when my system detected "Gun", or "Knife" it will alert security by using sound alarm.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows**

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound("sound_file.wav", FLAG)
```

or just a beep

```
import winsound

dur = 500 # as millisecond
freq = 2000 # sound frequency
winsound.Beep(freq, dur)
```

you can check the document 
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/winsound.html

**For other OS (Linux, Mac etc.)**

```
import os

os.system("sound_file.wav&")
```

Comment: thank for reply, i have import pygame, but i don't know why i combine the result and pygame it doesn't  work properly

Answer (score 0):

Insert loop

```
import winsound
if category_index=='index of knife':
    windsound.beep(duration(ms),frequency)
else:
    pass
```